# Understanding Python Error Message regarding Mixer Module for Audio

Tags: python, macos, mixer

I am receiving an error message (included below) when I try to run my gaming program with sound. I have a MacBook Air, 2017 and I am running Mac OS 10.13.6. After looking at this error message included below, I am wondering:

1. Does this look like a programming error or that the mixer module is not installed?
2. Is it not installed because I am running an older Mac OS?
3. If the answer is yes to #2, what are my options moving forward that do not involve buying a new computer?

Thanks for your patience. I am a new programmer, and this is my first post. If I am breaking any posting formats/conventions, it is only due to my own ignorance, and I apologize. If so, please set me straight. Thanks!

```
pygame 2.2.0 (SDL 2.0.22, Python 3.11.0)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
/Users/lens14/Desktop/python_work/alien_invasion/alien_invasion.py:40: RuntimeWarning: use mixer: dlopen(/Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/mixer.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmp3lame.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libsndfile.1.0.34.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
        /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
(ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/mixer.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmp3lame.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libsndfile.1.0.34.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
        /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown))
  self.bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Game_bullet.wav')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lens14/Desktop/python_work/alien_invasion/alien_invasion.py", line 354, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lens14/Desktop/python_work/alien_invasion/alien_invasion.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Game_bullet.wav')
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(missing_msg)
NotImplementedError: mixer module not available (ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/mixer.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmp3lame.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libsndfile.1.0.34.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
        /Users/lens14/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown))
```

So far:

1. I have tried running the program without any sound commands, and it works fine.
2. I watched an online tutorial about adding sound commands. The tutorial seemed understandable, so I just integrated the instruction into my code.
3. I tried cutting and pasting pieces of the error message into my search browser, but nothing seemed really definitive on what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same mac os version and the same problem in pygame 2.4.0. I installed pygame version 2.0.2 and everything works fine. It would be good to determine which maximum version of pygame works correctly in High Sierra)